How can I get the index to update after removing a book from my list
This is a snippet of my code and i want to be able to ge the Id to update to the correct position of each element after removing a book from my list, not sure how to achieve this.
Right now if i try and remove book with Id = 1, then the book with Id = 2 is put in first place but Id is not changed or the index of the element. Whats a good approach to fix this issue?
Main program
Book class
